# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, bitrise

Bitrise build is failing with the following error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'src'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.1.0/google-services-4.1.0.pom
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.1.0/google-services-4.1.0.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.1.0/google-services-4.1.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.1.0/google-services-4.1.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :

I know the alternative temporary solution of using maven. But do anyone know why the problem is happening suddenly and a permanent solution?

Comment: I've the same problem with a local gradle sync. I checked the Google's Maven Repository and it seems empty (com.google.gms).

Comment: For now, I've just added maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' } under repositories and the build have passed. Thanks to @David Sucharda.  As mentioned in other posts this solution is a temporary fix till we know what happened to the google() and jcenter() resources.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed by adding this to repositories:

```
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
```

**https://** prefix is important, otherwise it could use address as relative path on your build machine.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I've just added:

```
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
```

under repositories and the build have passed. Thanks to [David Sucharda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10169723/david-sucharda) for the solution. As mentioned in other posts this solution is a temporary fix till we know what happened to the google() and jcenter() resources.