# Ionic 3 prod release build issue with com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating release APK using the following versions : node - 8.12.0 gradle - 4.10.2 ionic CLI - 4.0.5 Cordova - 8.0.0

When I run the

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I am getting the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * Where:
Build file '/app/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 94
 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
 > Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.pom
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.jar
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.pom
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Today there is a problem with repositories. It seems no one can build a project [Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708030/could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-1-0)

Comment: I tried with the shared solution. But it's not working for me